# StatusBar белый в Android 6.0

Tags: java, android

Меняю цвет StatusBar на `#0d0d0d` и во всех версиях Android всё нормально, но в Android 6.0 он почему-то белый. Не могу понять с чем это связано. Гугление не помогло.

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

} else {
    Window window = getWindow();

    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#0d0d0d"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Android 5.0 Lollipop предоставил тему `Material Design` которая автоматически задает цвет статус бара основанный на значении `colorPrimaryDark`.

Это так же поддерживается и на более ранних версиях Android.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне нужно именно программно...

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `Color.parseColor("#0d0d0d")` использовать `ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.yourcolor)`